# Updating old mysqli code to new PHP 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have recently updated the PHP on my server to 5.4 and I was going through my code updating it to match. When I got to the point of upgrading my database queries I began having problems that I cannot solve. Everything worked before and all I have been changing about the SQL is the procedural call function names. For example:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, “SQL query”);
```

now becomes,

```
 $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($mysqli);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sqlReq);
$sqlReq = "SQL query";
```

I have gone through many forms of error checking and now know that,

```
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sqlReq);
```

is returning “false” so I get the error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt in /file/location/

for the bind parameters. In the code below I have removed the error checking because I know that it will fail any error checking but I don’t understand why. So what I am asking is, what am I doing wrong with the new mysqli for PHP 5.4

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
$sqlReq = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name = ?"; 
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($mysqli);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sqlReq);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $variable0);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $variable1, $variable2, $variable3);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);   
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: Sidenote: If that's part of your working code, `“ ”` those curlys will kill your code. Use `" "`

Comment: The curly quotes came from me editing the code in MS Word before posting on this site.

Comment: Ohhhh Lordie, don't use that. Use a code editor, or at the very least Notepad. **Notedpad++** is a good open source editor; use that instead. There are others though.

Comment: No that’s not what I am saying. I have the code in an IDE. I copied the code in question and wrote this post in MS Word to format it before posting it on stack overflow. The block of code that has these curly quotes is not source code. It’s just an example of the format change I am making.